# Server Side Validation: Update label class on redirect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

For a server side validation, on the redirect back to the submitting page, I want the relevant notice by the offending field.

One way to do this, a really bad hack, using php, would be, after submission:

```
if($firstname =="") {
  header("Location: register.php?f=1");
 }
```

Then, at the top of the submitting page:

```
<?
   $fn_ck= $_GET['f'];
?>
```

Then in the body:

```
<form method="POST" name="register" action="activate.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label id="l_fn" class="<? if($fn_ck==1){ echo 'warning'; } else { echo 'normal'; } ?>">First Name</label>

<input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text"> 
<input type="submit">
```

Where the class 'warning' colors the words 'First Name' in red.

But let's say there are several fields missing on the submit, using my hack, I get a link that looks like:

```
https://sample[dot]com/register.php?f=1&l=1&email=1&password=1 ... etc
```

So, that is kind of ugly. Plus the user can manually change the link and the red warning 'lights' will go off.

I am looking for a way where I can accomplish the same thing, but somehow, on the redirect, where the code knows which fields require the warning, can locate the label in question and update it with the 'warning' class.

---

EDIT

Also, to repopulate the fields the user already had completed as well.

Comment: I would not consider this a hack. If you dont want the get parameters in the url, you can use sessions instead

Comment: I don't think there is any easy way of doing this with server-side. Personally, I like to use AJAX when dealing with form submissions. When the form is submitted, an AJAX request is sent to another script that deals **strictly** with processing the request such as validating fields and making changes to the database. By using AJAX, the form does not get reloaded -- so I do not need to repopulate the fields. So, my only concern ends up being just having to display the errors, if any, using JavaScript.